# In ASP.NET MVC, how to write model so checkbox in view corresponds to integer in database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a database column "WantsReply" that logically holds a boolean (bit) but is unfortunately implemented as an integer.  Any nonzero value means "yes" and zero means "no".

If I write

```
class Entry {
   [Column] public int WantsReply {get; set;}
}
```

in my model, and map it to a checkbox in the view using

```
Html.CheckBox( "WantsReply", View.Model.WantsReply )
```

then I get a conversion error when I submit the view.  On the other hand if I write

```
[Column] public bool WantsReply {get; set;}
```

then the view submit works OK but then I get a different conversion error when I run a query like

```
from entry in Entries select entry;
```

How can I resolve this impedance mismatch so that both queries and submits work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changing the type of the column property, why not map it to a new property?

```
public partial class Entry {
    public bool WantsReplyAsBool
    {
        get
        {
            return WantsReply != 0;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                WantsReply = 1;
            }
            else
            { 
                WantsReply = 0;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The integer property can be private, if you like.  Use the bool property in your view.